# Iterate through select options

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and have been  experimenting with it for the last couple of days and have been successful with it until I got to this point. I am working on an edit users page and I have problem choosing the right role from a list that is already populated from the datbase.
//this is the select user drop down

```
  <select id="ddlUsers" name="ddlUsers" >
    <option value="0">--Select User--</option>
    <%for(Usertable user:usertableModel.getAllUsertables()){ %>
      <option id="<%=user.getUserid() %>" value="<%=user.getUserid() %>" 
          onclick= "showUserRole('<%=user.getRole().getRoleid() %>' )">     <%=user.getLastname() %> , <%=user.getFirstname() %>
   </option>
   <%} %>
```

// this is the select option for which I want to select the right role of the user selected from the first drop down.

```
<select name="ddlRoles">
  <%for(Role r:roleModel.getAllRoles()){ %>
    <option value="<%=r.getRoleid() %>"><%=r.getRolename() %></option>
  <%} %>
</select>
```

//here is the jquery I tried to use

```
function showUserRole(role){
   $('#ddlRoles').each(function(){
      if($('option', this).val() == role){
    $('option', this).attr("selected","selected");
      }
  });
 }
```

but obviously its not working.... so any help is appreciated... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ddlRoles` is the value of `name` `attribute` you cant use it as `id selector`. try this

if `<select name="ddlRoles">`

then

```
function showuserRole(role){
    $('select[name="ddlRoles"]').val(role);
}
```

else change it as `<select id="ddlRoles">`

then

```
function showuserRole(role){
    $('select#ddlRoles').val(role);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been trying exactly what 3nigma posted for a while with out a result only because I forgot to set the select id "ddlRoles"... now everything works great . I even tried your suggestion and it works perfect and is a shorter syntax so I am gonna do it exactly as u did. Once again THANK YOU

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been trying exactly what 3nigma posted for a while with out a result only because I forgot to set the select id "ddlRoles"... now everything works great . I even tried your suggestion and it works perfect and is a shorter syntax so I am gonna do it exactly as u did. Once again THANK YOU

Comment: you are welcome buddy but i guess this is answer which given you correct direction and explanation.. you should mark this as accepted not the above. llollllzzzz

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#ddlRoles').find("option[value='"+role+"']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: This will work too, but it's simpler to use the .val() function on the select object.

Comment: Thank you very much I actually tried to use this already and wasn't working but now I know whats wrong with my code. I forgot to set the ID of the select tag for the roles as "ddlUsers". Thank you.

Comment: this is not the answer to be marked as accepted.. the exact problem was described in my answer with explannation and so logically my answer should be marked as accepted... lollzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your showuserRole function by just settings the value of #ddlRoles to the role you are passing in.

```
function showuserRole(role){
    $('#ddlRoles').val(role);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works. I needed to set the id of the select for it to work.